# Load page again immediately after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very new with `JS` and I have a very strange problem with my webpage.
In some section of the page, there are images which have `zoon-in effect` on mouse over which wrote in `jQuery`. The problem is that in order to see the `zoom-in effect`, you need to load the page again. It does not appear at the first load of the page.

Now the `<script>` tag and the reference link to the `jQuery` library are at the button of the page (below the `</body>` tag). If I move them to the top of the page, the `zoom-in effect` does not working at all.

Can someone know how to solve this problem? What can cause it?
If not, there is some way to load the page immediately again? I know it is not elegant way but if I have no other solution thats what I will do.

Thanks

**JQuery**

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.extend({

    hoverZoom: function (settings) {

        var defaults = {
            overlay: true,
            overlayColor: '#343434',
            overlayOpacity: 0.7,
            zoom: 25,
            speed: 300
        };

        var settings = $.extend(defaults, settings);

        return this.each(function () {

            var s = settings;
            var hz = $(this);
            var image = $('img', hz);

            image.load(function () {

                if (s.overlay === true) {
                    $(this).parent().append('<div class="zoomOverlay" />');
                    $(this).parent().find('.zoomOverlay').css({
                        opacity: 0,
                        display: 'block',
                        backgroundColor: s.overlayColor
                    });
                }

                var width = $(this).width();
                var height = $(this).height();

                $(this).fadeIn(1000, function () {
                    $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'none');
                    hz.hover(function () {
                        $('img', this).stop().animate({
                            height: height + s.zoom,
                            marginLeft: -(s.zoom),
                            marginTop: -(s.zoom)
                        }, s.speed);
                        if (s.overlay === true) {
                            $(this).parent().find('.zoomOverlay').stop().animate({
                                opacity: s.overlayOpacity
                            }, s.speed);
                        }
                    }, function () {
                        $('img', this).stop().animate({
                            height: height,
                            marginLeft: 0,
                            marginTop: 0
                        }, s.speed);
                        if (s.overlay === true) {
                            $(this).parent().find('.zoomOverlay').stop().animate({
                                opacity: 0
                            }, s.speed);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="portItemContainer">
    <div class="portItem">
        <a href="Portfolio/index.html" target="_blank" class="zoom grey"><img src="Images/meals.png" alt="" /></a>
        <h5>Meals APP</h5>
        <h6>FRONTEND / UX / CREATIVE</h6>
        <a href="Portfolio/index.html" target="_blank">Visit The Website</a>
        <p>
            some text
        </p>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.zoom {
    width:230px;
    height:148px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #959595;
    background: #fff url(../Images/loader.gif) no-repeat center;
}

.zoom img { display:none }

.zoomOverlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    bottom:0; right:0;
    display:none;
    background-image:url(../Images/zoom.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: "Put the scripts at the end of body" means before the ending body tag, not after. I don't know how browser will parse the scripts not in the body, I recommend you to put them *inside* the body. And if you think about it, loading the page again after loading would need some state (not desirable), or you would have recursively reloading page.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I put them inside the body but the problem did not solved yet.

Comment: Have you got any console errors mate..??

Comment: Can you link us to the site? It would be much better to fix the issue than to refresh the page.

Comment: No console error and the page is not online yet. I tried to solve this issue before I will upload it with no success :/

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to fix the issue than to refresh the page, however, to answer your question, you could use a GET parameter to refresh the page once.

```
var reloadKey = 'rl001';
var url = window.location.href;
testForReload();
function testForReload() {
    if (url.indexOf('?') < 0) {
        reloadPage();
        return false;
    }
    var getParams = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('?') + 1);
    if (getParams.indexOf(reloadKey) < 0) {
        reloadPage();
    }
}
function reloadPage() {
    var q = (url.indexOf('?') < 0) ? '?' : '&';
    window.location = url + q + reloadKey;
}
```